# MVC - use C# to fill ViewBag with Json Action Result

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewbag, actionresult

I have an MVC website with C# code behind. I am using an ActionResult, that returns Json.

I am trying to put something in the ViewBag but it doesn't appear to work.

The code looks like this -

```
    public ActionResult GetStuff(string id)
    {
        ViewBag.Id = id;

        stuff = new StuffFromDatabase(id);

        return this.Json(stuff , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

The "id" does not appear go in the ViewBag.Id.

Can I put the id in the ViewBag this way? If not any suggestions on how I should do it?
Thanks!

Comment: How are you using ViewBag in the View?

Comment: I actually just want the value I put in the ViewBag to be accessible in my C# code when I do a POST. 
Like -   
             var currentId = ViewBag.Id

Comment: I'm confused.. as you are already passing id as an argument?

Comment: The id is not in the "stuff" that I am returning in the Json object. I want to do a POST to C# code behind like **[HttpPost]** **public ActionResult GotStuf(FormCollection formCollection)** **{** var currentId = ViewBag.Id; **}**

Comment: So you want to set ViewBag.Id in the View..

Comment: According to "webdeveloper" below. It doesn't sound like I can do what I am trying to do. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Yes (to your last comment Lews Therin)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another solution can be this: if you want access "id" property after post action that return json result, you can return a complex object containing all data required:

```
public ActionResult GetStuff(string id)  
{  
    ViewBag.Id = id;  

    stuff = new StuffFromDatabase(id);  

    return this.Json(new { stuff = stuff, id = id } , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);  
}
```

After, in json returned value, you can access all properties like in this example:

```
$.post(action, function(returnedJson) {
   var id = returnedJson.id;
   var stuff = returnedJson.stuff;
});
```

Comment: I actually need to access it inside C# POST code. I want to store the id in the ViewBag.Id then reference the ViewBag.Id when I do a POST.

Comment: I am going to use this RoBYCoNTe (along with some other code) Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

ViewBag is only available server-side. You are sending a json string back to the browser, presumably the browser then does something with it. You will have to send the id in the json response as follows:

```
return this.Json(new { Id = id, Data = stuff }, JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet);
```

Answer (score 1):

You trying to set `ViewBag.Id` in Json result? `ViewBag` used in views, not in `Json`.

**Added**

As I can see from comments, then you trying to use it in javascript, you can do such things. Try this:

```
return this.Json(new {stuff, id} , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Then you can access this data in javascript.